# Two radio button getting selected in Angular due to ngModel

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-forms, angular-ngmodel

When i do without form or normal approach it works fine but after using template-driven angular form and using ngModel on formcontrol i get this bug..

```
<div class="con" *ngFor="let Qtn of Q; let i = index">
      <p class="question">{{ Qtn.q }}</p>
      <div class="container" *ngFor="let op of Qtn.op">
        <label 
          >
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="{{ i }}"
            value="{{ op.answer }}"
            ngModel
            #{{i}}
          /> {{ op.op }}
        </label>
        
      </div>
      <p #result></p>
      <hr />
    </div>
```

---

Appservice.ts

```
Q=[{
        q:"What is the full form of  HTML",
        op:[{
          op:"Hyper Text Markup Language",answer:"correct"
        },{
          op:"Hello talk me less",answer:"wrong"
        },{
          op:"Hindi Telugu Marathi Lingo",answer:"wrong"
        }]
      },
      {
        q:"What is 4 + 4?",
        op:[{
          op:"4",answer:"correct"
        },{
          op:"Four",answer:"wrong"
        },{
          op:"40",answer:"wrong"
        }]
      }]
```

Output bug is something like this>>
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdiPm.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try providing a static `name` attribute instead of dynamic one. Check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#defining_a_radio_group) for more info.

```
        <label>
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="answer"
            value="{{ op.answer }}"
            ngModel
            #{{i}}
          /> {{ op.op }}
        </label>
```